# Why does `man -k cron` say `vixie-cron (rpm)` for some results, and how do I read those pages?

Tags: rhel, man, rpm

I'm trying to find out some details regarding [cron and /etc/cron.d/](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/does-rhel-execute-all-cronjob-files-under-etc-cron-d) on a RedHat system. Ironically, my answer is viewable within the [vixie-cron-*.src.rpm](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/4663/does-rhel-execute-all-cronjob-files-under-etc-cron-d/4756#4756) for this package, but the the man pages for `cron` don't match the text which is provided by the `vixie-cron` RPM.

If I search my MANPATH for the keyword `cron`, it shows me some results like `vixie-cron          (rpm)`. What does this `(rpm)` tag mean, why are these manpages not installed on the system and can I view those manpages?

```
$ man -k cron
/etc/anacrontab [anacrontab] (5)  - configuration file for anacron
anacron              (8)  - runs commands periodically
anacron             (rpm) - A cron-like program that can run jobs lost during downtime.
cron                 (8)  - daemon to execute scheduled commands (ISC Cron V4.1)
crontab              (1)  - maintain crontab files for individual users (ISC Cron V4.1)
crontab              (1p)  - schedule periodic background work
crontab              (5)  - tables for driving cron (ISC Cron V4.1)
crontabs            (rpm) - Root crontab files used to schedule the execution of programs.
vixie-cron          (rpm) - The Vixie cron daemon for executing specified programs at set times.
```

Note that there is no page for `vixie-cron`, and the vixie-cron package doesn't actually provide any manpages named `vixie-cron`

```
$ man vixie-cron
No manual entry for vixie-cron
$ rpm -q --whatprovides /usr/bin/crontab
vixie-cron-4.1-77.el5_4.1
$ rpm -q --list vixie-cron
/etc/cron.d
/etc/pam.d/crond
/etc/rc.d/init.d/crond
/etc/sysconfig/crond
/usr/bin/crontab
/usr/sbin/crond
/usr/share/man/man1/crontab.1.gz
/usr/share/man/man5/crontab.5.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/cron.8.gz
/usr/share/man/man8/crond.8.gz
/var/spool/cron
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command `man -k` queries against a pre-compiled database and not the manual pages themselves.

I suspect that entries may have been made in the database (see `man mandb` for details) for pages that don't actually exist. I am not familiar enough with the RPM mechanisms to know how this could have happened.

In a similar vein, there is considerable flexibility in what section a given manual page may claim to live. For example, on my system `man Carp` claims to be in section "3perl" where the underlying file is stored in `.../man3/Carp.3perl.gz`. The commands

```
man Carp
man -s 3 Carp
man -s 3perl Carp
```

all yield the same page while `man -s 3junk Carp` complains that there is no such entry.

You might find `mlocate` (a.k.a. `locate`) to be useful for hunting files by name. I presume it is available for RedHat since <s>redacted</s>@redhat.com is credited as the author.

Comment: Regarding the statement "I suspect that entries may have been made in the database for pages that don't actually exist." -- These `(rpm)` entries show up on nearly most RHEL/CentOS system that I have access to, at different companies with different environments and procedures. This means that these rogue pages weren't added to the database by accident, and these entries exist due to a default option in the CentOS/RHEL operating system.